# What graphic card drivers to install in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, ubuntu-10.04, ati-mobility-radeon

I have an ATI Mobility Radeon 4650 HD graphics card.
And I have upgrated to Ubuntu 10.04

What drivers should I install for my graphics card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be sure of your graphic card by checking in Terminal.

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

If the system shows you that `None known.`, you've to use [Fglrx Driver](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=423584).

However, if the system supports the type of graphic system you use, for *HD 4xxx / R700 based cards*
according to you stated, it can easily be installed using *System* => *Administration* => *Hardware Drivers.*

Restart xserver by logging out and back in, or typing `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`.Check status flag

```
glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
```

Check functionality by invoking glxgears.

```
$ glxgears
```

Change overlay type to Xvideo if video upscaling looks blocky.

```
$ sudo aticonfig --ovt=Xv
```

fore more, you can take a look at [Ubuntu Documentations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver),and  this [guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-ati-video-card-in-you-linux-system.html)