# how to enable HD video acceleration for ATI card in Ubuntu?  

Tags: ubuntu, hdvideo

I have video card ATI Radeon 2600 XT. Operating system: Ubuntu. Question: how to enable HD video acceleration for ATI card in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATI doesn't have video acceleration under linux. However, ATI seems to be working on a new driver which would bring support for VA-API. (As far as I know).
On Linux, you can use "ffmpeg-mt" (if you got multi-core cpu, it'll decode the movie with X core) or just give extra parameters for mplayer.

Like: *mplayer -fs -really-quiet -vo xv -ao oss -vfm ffmpeg -lavdopts fast=1:skiploopfilter=all $file*

You can give these parameters in smplayer, options, advanced.
Just type the following there:

> -fs -really-quiet -vo xv -ao oss -vfm ffmpeg -lavdopts fast=1:skiploopfilter=all

Comment: While they don't support Xv directly, they do support OpenGL and quite a few video players can output through that. I recall ATI having issues with OpenGL video while on a composite desktop however, but that was years ago and is likely to be fixed by now.

Comment: Don't hope for such thing when it comes to ATI. Well..worth a try. Smplayer, and choose the gl (ATI) output. Maybe it'll work. Maybe. :/ || Thanks for the edit (Nik).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Fglrx Driver](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=423584).  if the system supports the type of graphic system you use, for HD 4xxx / R700 based cards according to you stated, it can easily be installed using *System  => Administration => Hardware Drivers.* .. also you'd take a look at [that one](https://superuser.com/questions/126630/what-graphic-card-drivers-to-install-in-ubuntu-10-04/126638#126638) too.